# Realtime Database Rules not working as expected

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am facing a puzzling situation with Realtime Database Rules.

The rules below are working, they allow me to write data to FirstCollection:

```js
{
  "rules": {
    "FirstCollection": {
      ".read": true,
      "$Section": {
        ".write": "(auth!=null)"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This second set of rules used to work until yesterday, and it no longer works:

```js
{
  "rules": {
    "FirstCollection": {
      ".read": true,
      "$Section": {
        ".write": "(auth!=null)&&((auth.uid=='98ab..myOwnUID..23YZ')||(auth.uid=='98ab..aSecondUID..23YZ'))"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have checked everything I could think about including the exact value of myOwnUID.

Can any experienced user spot the issue or any mistake I could be making (or could have made)?

Comment: Rules on their own do nothing and they only become active once you execute some code against them. Please edit your question to show the minimal code with which you get a problem against these rules. In that code, be sure to show how it satisfies the rules (e.g. log the UID and show us that cod and its output too.

Comment: @Frank_van_Puffelen. I see, it is in a React app. I need to see how I can extract what you're requesting.

Comment: @Frank_van_Puffelen. ..... while checking I finally solved my problem. I was doing something in my app changing the current user without knowing it ! Now things are clear. ... You may have helped me without answering my question :)

Comment: Good to hear Michel!  --- Do you think a self-answer might be helpful for others going forward here? If not, any ideas how to bring closure here?

Comment: @Frank_van_Puffelen. I just posted my answer, you may take a look and see.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the issue I was having. The rules have in fact nothing wrong.

What happens is that the code in my app is creating a new user with the *auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword* API function. And since this function has the "annoying side effect" of signing in as the newly created user, when I then hit the rules in the flow of the app my *auth.uid* is no longer what I expect it to be, thus explaining why the rules fires.